# Create a boxplot for each column of a data frame, according to two label columns from another data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I have a data frame with 25 features as columns, call it `df1`. In another data frame, call it `df2`, there are two label columns that I want to use. The first label column is `cancertype` and it has only three cancer types. The second label is `stage` and it has 4 different stages.  Both `df1` and `df2` have the same exact samples in the rows, in the same order.

I want to create a boxplot for each feature, where the x-axis would be the three cancer types, and for each cancer type, I'd have 4 box plots according to the stage. So in the end, I'll have 25 boxplots, each one for each feature.

Here is a plot as an example:

[image]

So here instead of 0.5, 1, and 2, I'd have the three cancer types, and instead of Orange juice and Ascorbic juice, I'll have the 4 stages of cancer. And of course, instead of Tooth Length, I'll have the values of the feature. How can I do that in R?

Here is an example of the data, I combined the two labels columns `stage` and `cancertype` from `df2`, to some of the features of `df1`, just so you guys see what the data looks like:

```
structure(list(`CD4-T-cells` = c(-0.126653261025908, -0.146944662222103, 
-0.0115148964617506, -0.215846341670589, -0.146791213061172, 
-0.219857803332179, -0.17081620282989, -0.0891711254320417, -0.0874442820512679, 
-0.220366749282219, -0.133508075707128, -0.193271241796752, -0.201211825907853, 
-0.125225983272556, -0.115043218071495), `CD8-T-cells` = c(-0.157666852910288, 
-0.232728699747416, -0.0160616032665578, -0.209410515957277, 
-0.202956751240547, -0.175764455863453, -0.323439446327317, -0.0338852795521566, 
-0.135834830888521, -0.141126851397699, -0.255009952032843, -0.213879070793134, 
-0.183317103095461, -0.189072789833267, -0.259816019334781), 
    `T-helpers` = c(-0.22607814653843, -0.215166591267584, -0.00118837391747009, 
    -0.312608050611363, -0.341117207247747, -0.294448125003604, 
    -0.292393762983215, -0.118961302821571, -0.253841509210292, 
    -0.183748456919948, -0.260611567417525, -0.265980836082014, 
    -0.200401095547006, -0.189306997555047, -0.284547076718132
    ), `NK-cells` = c(-0.0768979654779382, -0.156845903079279, 
    -0.00175695677961327, 0.0435753727359533, -0.113414879053929, 
    -0.0719972487895254, -0.173138898156026, -0.0363772958157232, 
    -0.113696954024299, -0.0452152425828402, -0.169035653930283, 
    -0.0850518565032839, -0.0992324194948109, -0.0820755296254414, 
    -0.158947253410155), cancertype = c("Melanoma", "Urothelial Bladder Carcinoma", 
    "Urothelial Bladder Carcinoma", "Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", 
    "Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", "Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", 
    "Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", "Melanoma", "Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", 
    "Melanoma", "Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", 
    "Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", "Urothelial Bladder Carcinoma"
    ), stage = c("stage1", "stage2", "stage4", "Stage3", " Stage2", 
    "Stage4", "Stage1", "Stage1", "Stage1", " Stage1", "Stage3", 
    "Stage1", "Stage3", "Stage3", "Stage4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Pt1", 
"Pt10", "Pt101", "Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", 
"Pt24", "Pt26", "Pt27", "Pt28", "Pt29", "Pt3"))
```

## EDIT -

Apparently, I have too many features so presenting the plots together with `facet_wrap` would make a mess. Therefore, what I need is to save each plot individually inside a list, and then for example, I call mylist[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvz7X.png)] and I get the first plot, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires a bit of data wrangling and cleaning but perhaps something like this will fit your needs:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(cancertype, stage), names_to = "feature") |> 
  mutate(stage = stringr::str_to_title(stage),
         stage = stringr::str_trim(stage)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(cancertype, value, fill = stage)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~str_wrap(.x, 25)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  facet_wrap(~feature) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**EDIT** And to output one plot per feature as a list you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(cancertype, stage), names_to = "feature") |> 
  mutate(stage = stringr::str_to_title(stage),
         stage = stringr::str_trim(stage)) |> 
  group_split(feature) |>
  lapply(function(.data) {
    ggplot(.data, aes(cancertype, value, fill = stage)) +
      geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = ~str_wrap(.x, 25)) +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
      labs(title = unique(.data$feature)) +
      theme_bw()
  })
```

Comment: Apparently, I have too many features so presenting the plots together with `facet_wrap` would make a mess. Could you please change the code so that each plot is saved individually inside a list? so that for example, I call `mylist[[1]]` and I get the first plot, and so on.

Comment: Not a big deal. See my edit.

Comment: I'm getting weird plots in both cases. Please look at my second edit. This is for the second code chunk, why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what you mean by "weird". Also, what second edit do you mean?

Comment: I edited my question. Please look at the plot I'm getting ( under **EDIT 2**), it's not a boxplot.

Comment: Well, I would guess that the issue is that for whatever reason your `value` column isn't  a numeric but a character instead. Try with `as.numeric(value)`.

Comment: Oh man, didn't notice that. Thank you so much :)